# Cannot rename MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me to discover syntax error in my rename_table script. What i want is add date to the table name, but something goes wrong.
Now here's the code:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y');
$query = "RENAME order TO order".$date;
if(mysql_query($ren)){
...
```

Comment: order is a reserved key word you need to backtick it

Comment: In mysql There is the different syntax for Rename command. its `RENAME TABLE TAB_NAME TO NEW_TAB_NAME`

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. They are officially deprecated. Refer to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The problem wasn't in backticks. Syntax error was the reason why the script did not execute. So only Ankit Bajpai's answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backticks for `order` as it is a reserved keyword. Also you are executing the query wrongly.

```
if(mysql_query($ren))          
                 ^
```

Replace `$ren` with `$query` as your query is stored in a variable `$query`, not `$ren`..

So try with

```
$query = "RENAME TABLE `order` TO order".$date;
if(mysql_query($query))
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$query = "RENAME order TO order".$date;
```

to

```
$query = "RENAME `order` TO `order".$date."`";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use - sign as table name, use _ or dmy format 06nov2014

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = date('d-m-Y');
$query = "RENAME `order` TO `order".$date."`";
if(mysql_query($ren))
```